# problems with fonctions differents in folders (Makefile)

Tags: c++, makefile, header, definition

I have a message in my terminal due to the fact that differents functions / libraries were not declared. I use makefile, but it may be an error because of the headers but I can't find out. Here is a resume of the code + the terminal :

coord.hpp :

```
#ifndef COORD_HPP
#define COORD_HPP
#include <vector>
#include <string>    
#include <array>
using namespace std

class Coord {     
    public:
    Coord();                   //constructor 1
    Coord(int lig, int col);   //constructor 2
};
#endif
```

coord.cpp:

```
#include "doctest.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include "coord.hpp"

Coord::Coord():Coord{0,0}{ 
}
Coord::Coord(int lig, int col):num_ligne{lig}, num_colonne{col}{
    assert(lig >= 0 && lig <= 20 && "too much lignes");
    assert(col >= 0 && col <= 20 && "too much columns");
}
```

ants.hpp

```
#ifndef FOURMIS_HPP
#define FOURMIS_HPP

class Ants{
    public:
    Ants(Coord a, int n);   //constructor. 
    Coord coord();   //coordonates of one Ant
    int num();         //number of one Ant

    Coord fCoord;
    int fNum;
};
#endif
```

ants.cpp

```
#include "coord.hpp"
#include "fourmis.hpp"

Fourmi::Fourmi(Coord a, int n){
    fNum = n;
}

Coord Fourmi::coord(){
    return fCoord;
}

int Fourmi::num(){
    return fNum;
}
```

So, here is my terminal :

```
my.name@jupyterhub:~/Project$ make test
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall  -c place.cpp
In file included from place.cpp:1:ants.hpp:6:17: error: expected ')' before 'a'
    6 |     Ants(Coord a, int n); 
      |           ~     ^~
      |                 )
In file included from place.cpp:1:
fourmis.hpp:9:5: error: 'Coord' does not name a type    9 |     Coord coord(); 
      |     ^~~~~
fourmis.hpp:24:5: error: 'Coord' does not name a type
   24 |     Coord fCoord;
      |     ^~~~~
             ^~~~~~~~
place.hpp:6:16: error: expected ')' before 'x'
    6 |     Place(Coord x);
      |          ~     ^~
      |
```

- And I skip the '*was not declared in this scope*' errors... My makefile is ok I think : it surely comes from the headers, if someone could help me...
- when I try to put a test int ants.cpp (with doctest) it puts me '*error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion*'. But when I try it in coord.cpp it is totally ok.

A free hug for the one who can help me :)

Comment: ants.h needs to include coord.h, otherwise `Coord` is not declared in ants.h

Comment: My bad, I forgot to put it in my topic but I already did it in my code before the bug (it is edited now)

Comment: you added the includes in the source, but they are missing in the header

Comment: hmm i am not sure to fully understand :/ in which header should I put the includes (and which ones?)

Comment: ants.h needs to include coord.h, otherwise Coord is not declared in ants.h

Comment: btw it seems you changed names for posting here, but not consistenly. The error complains about some `Place` which is not present in the code and `ants.cpp` defines members of a class `Fourmi` which is not declared in the code you posted. This causes unnecessary confusion

Comment: aha i change in english for the topic (usually it is in french :D ). And it seems to work better, but the doctest is still not recognised

Comment: As a matter of style, `coord.h` *should* be included in `ants.h` because the latter depends on declarations appearing in the former.  It is sufficient, however, for `coord.h` to be `#include`d before `ants.h` in every translation unit that uses the latter.  The style issue is that `ants.h` and the entities declared within are unnecessarily difficult to use if they carry extra requirements for declaring other things, and that gets much, much worse as the program becomes more complex.